# Changing Implementation/Class at runtime

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, data-structures

I am looking for real world examples of (open source) programs (or algorithms) that change the concrete class of an object (or variable) at runtime.

An example of such behaviour in Java could look like the code snipper below.
Here, a `LinkedList`, which performs well in the context of frequent inserts and/or removes, is changed into an `ArrayList`, which performs well in the context of random access and iteration.

```
List myList = new LinkedList(); 
/* Lots of inserts */
...
myList = new ArrayList( myList ); // 'change' into different class
/* Lots of iteration */
...
```

The Java example above changes between `LinkedList` and `ArrayList` for the
sake of performance.

However, examples in any language, for any data structure, using any technique*, and for any reason are welcome.

*Technique: plain and simple like in the example above, or
using `become:` in SmallTalk,or `__class__` in Python, or ...

Comment: At general, a question that asks for a library is off topic here. I also cannot understand the purpose behind your question, as it is clear you understand what's the benefit of doing so, and how it can be done from your example.

Comment: **I am not looking for a library**, I am looking for "example code", i.e., other scenarios in which programmers change data structure/ classes of an object.
The purpose behind my question is that I need to build the case that this is a common enough pattern to provide language abstractions for.

Comment: I often create arrays dynamically in an initialization phase and use an ArrayList to do so, Then I know that no further changes will happen I transform it to an plain old array to reduce memory overhead and increase performance a bit.

Comment: @MrSmith42 This is very relevant for my study! Is this private or public software? Are you in the possibility to provide me pointers to those projects?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check use cases for `become` method in Smalltalk. The method changes the class of the instance at runtime (or to change all references to the instance to reference different instance)

Become is commonly used to grow/shrink collections, e.g. Dictionary with more buckets, ByteArray with bigger buffer etc. It is possible to convert from SmallInteger to BigIntegers (former are limited in size, latter are not, but are much slower), and the programmer wouldn't even notice (this is reasonable only if you have mutable integers, therefore this is not how this is done in Smalltalk. But it could be :)

Another case might be when loading an instance from serialized form back into the running system, and updating its class to the newest version.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, look at #become in Smalltalk (for instance MIT licensed Pharo.org).

Beside the examples already given #become is for instance usefull when
you work with proxies. Think of a proxy object within an ORM framework like
Glorp where you first have the proxy and when the real full object is needed
it can be loaded from a database and easily all references will be switched.

Another example is the Fuel framework in Pharo.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is relevant but maybe the usage of spy (partial mocks) also fits your description (see http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/Spy.html):

An example:

```
Person person = new Person();
person = spy(person);
doReturn("dominiek").when(person).getName();
```

Behind the scenes a subclass is created and the behavior of the class is altered according to the users' behavior declarations.

Answer (score 1):

I've just run across an instance of this in the (Python) **NLTK source**. The [LazyCorpusLoader](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/corpus/util.html) (an object used to load a dataset from disk) "morphs" into the dataset itself. Here's the relevant section of the linked source code (creating a dataset object and then becoming it):

```
    corpus = self.__reader_cls(root, *self.__args, **self.__kwargs)

    # This is where the magic happens!  Transform ourselves into
    # the corpus by modifying our own __dict__ and __class__ to
    # match that of the corpus.

    args, kwargs  = self.__args, self.__kwargs
    name, reader_cls = self.__name, self.__reader_cls

    self.__dict__ = corpus.__dict__
    self.__class__ = corpus.__class__
```

Here's the rationale given (in the header of the same file) for this technique:

> LazyCorpusLoader is a proxy object which is used to stand in for a
>   corpus object before the corpus is loaded.  This allows NLTK to
>   create an object for each corpus, but defer the costs associated
>   with loading those corpora until the first time that they're
>   actually accessed.

So the purpose of changing the class at runtime in this case is **to emulate lazy evaluation**.

*(Edit: Since I'm quoting verbatim from the NLTK source (Apache 2.0 license), here's the mandatory link to the license itself: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0)*